# Apache unable to find DocumentRoot even though it exists?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos

I've been setting up a local web server, but I'm having an issue with the following error when I start or restart the Apache `httpd` service.

Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/www/html/project1] does not exist

Now I've checked within the `html` folder and the `project1` folder does exist. I can write to that directory via FTP, and the ownership of the folder is for root. I've also checked SELinux and I can confirm that this has been disabled.

Here is my Virtual Host information:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@local.com
     DocumentRoot /www/html/project1
     ServerName local.project1.com
     ErrorLog logs/local.project1.com-error_log
     CustomLog logs/local.project1.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

What's going wrong?

**Edit**
I've checked to see the folder permissions on the folder, and here they are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2  apache  root  4096  Nov 20 15:32  project1
```

Apache is still giving the same errors.

Comment: Is Apache httpd running chrooted?

Comment: *the ownership of the folder is for root.* - make sure the user Apache runs under has permission to read and execute every directory in that path. Apache does not run as root by default (and should not).

Comment: I've changed the ownership of the folder to apache, but the error still persists. I've updated my answer to reflect this.